# Discord.js throws ReferenceError: message is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am in the process of making a bot that has features that only work on a specific server. The server is about trading cards, and I want to make a bot that can moderate the server, and that people can have fun with.

The error looks like this:

```
c:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Sky\index.js:10
  if (message.content === 'sky claim') {
  ^

ReferenceError: message is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (c:\Users\kelly\Desktop\Sky\index.js:10:3)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (c:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Sky\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (c:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Sky\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (c:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Sky\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (c:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Sky\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (c:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Sky\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (c:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Sky\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (c:\Users\REDACTED\Desktop\Sky\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:845:20)
```

The code for my Discord bot is here.

```js
client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (message.content === "sky claim") {
        message.channel.send("${message.author} claimed 250 SkyBucks. Spend SkyBucks on colored roles.");
        console.log("${message.author} executed command successfully");
    }
});`
```

I only added the part of the code that was giving the error.

Comment: There shouldn't be __more than__ 1 event of each type per application. Please read about [Command handling in Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/).

Comment: @Jakye That's obvious, it will automatically send all of the requests to the client which is a bad idea but you can add an require("events").emitter.setMaxListeners = "value" to fix this

Comment: @MrMythical tried that, got this error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read your error you should be able to find out why it doesn’t work:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === 'sky eBay') {
    message.channel.send('Our eBay store is @CollectAmazing, I will drop a link:');
    message.channel.send('https://www.ebay.com/str/collectamazing');
  }
})
```

Change all of the `client.on('message', msg` to `client.on('message', message`